# Nginx worker_processes and multi core cpu's - Do Hyper-threading cores count?

Tags: nginx, multi-core, threads, hyperthreading

Quite often, when reading about the recommended worker_processes for nginx it is stated that this should be set to the numbers of cores the server hosting nginx has.

We were wondering if we should count the number of HT cores for this as well?

Or do we just count the number of true physical cores?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case of HT, you better use [worker_cpu_affinity](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_cpu_affinity)

Answer (score 1):

As of today, you can configure both `worker_process` and `worker_cpu_affinity` to `auto` and it will handle automatically.